# Using Node.js without admin rights - sh: node: command not found

Tags: terminal, install, environment-variables

I've been following this guide (https://theshravan.net/blog/how-to-use-node-and-npm-without-installation-or-admin-rights/) to try to use Node.js on my work computer. The guide is for windows but most of the steps are the same for mac. I don't have admin rights so I'm using the binary to use node. When I run `npm -v` and `node -v`, i get the versions so it looks like everything is working. But, when I try to install packages with npm I get `sh: node: command not found`

My PATH looks like this: `PATH=$PATH:Tools/nodejs`

Comment: the directory seems wrong.. it is not absolute path to the nodejs I think. right click on the `nodejs`, hold alt, select copy nodejs as pathname. Use it. & prepending often is useful, than appending to the PATH.

Comment: are you using bash, or zsh ?

Comment: I am using bash

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use a guide for macOS? There are too many things which could have gone wrong that way, can you list the commands you used to install `node` (they should still be in the shell history)? Otherwise it will be difficult to find the issue.

Comment: And as ankii said: You need to add the full path to PATH, not just the part you did.

Comment: @klanomath what was your answer?

Comment: @klanomath go ahead then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked guide doesn't really help for macOS or Linux because of the different file & folder hierarchy compared to Winodws.

I recommend the followwing:

1. Download either the [LTS](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz) or the [latest version](https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.9.0/node-v13.9.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz) of node.js (both are direct download links!). Node.js download site: [Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) (no direct link).
2. Extract the node-v(ersion)x.y.z-darwin-x64.tar.gz and rename the resulting folder to *node*
3. Create a new folder *bin* in your home folder
4. Move the *node* folder to the bin folder
5. Add the following line to your .bash_profile:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/node/bin"
   ```

There is no need to download npm additionally because it's already included in the node archive.

---

If you want to install a newer version simply download the new node-v(ersion)x.y.z-darwin-x64.tar.gz file, extract it **and move its content to ~/bin/node/ replacing the old files and folders**.

Comment: Thanks alot! I ended up using nvm but this is also a good solution

Comment: I tried this, but I meet a pop up saying  "“node” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software." when I call `node -v`.

Comment: Note that on recent versions of macOS Zsh is the default shell instead of Bash and, you'll need to instead modify your .zshrc file for step 5. Here's a one-liner that will do it: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/node/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: @SonneyPatel - that no longer appears to be the case with the latest downloads from NodeJS, which appear to be signed properly, but if you're still seeing that, you should be able to run `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/bin/node/bin/node` to remove the file quarantine and then try again.